# Dependencies in c++

Tags: c++, dependencies, wxwidgets

For example, I have application with wxWidgets framework. It has many classes, which need to communicate with each other (get data, invoking some procedures etc.).
Can you advice me about some dependency injections or smth in C++?

In PHP I can wrote some class with **get(id)**, which will return objects of any type. But cpp has strong typing, so one function can return object of single type (overloading is not the answer I think)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to return different types by playing with pointers/references:-

1) In this case function would return base type.

```
class Base;
class Der1 : public Base
class Der2 : public Der1

Base* func ()  << It can return all objects in the heirarchy.
```

2) Return void* from function.

```
void* func ()  << It can return any type of object.
```

But in this case you need to take care while converting back to original pointer using static_cast.

Comment: MyObj* p = func("myobj"); will automatically cast pointer to MyObject in 2 variant, rigth?

Comment: In C yes. But in C++ no. You have to use explicit cast for that.